# Developing Web/Mobile Chat system

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a web base chat for administrators and a mobile chat application for the client.
Admins are on the web chat (asp.net c#) while the clients are using the android chat (java native code).

I have built the android chat system. I used GCM to send instant notification to the device. But now I dont know to send an instant notification to my web chat app. I am using web api. My android client sends messages to web api which in turn sends to notification to GCM. Pls how can I send an instant message to my administrator chat box (Built on MVC4) when the web api controll receives a message from the android app. 
I was thinking may be I could use html5 on my admin end but I dont know if I could get an instant message from GCM on html5.

Thanks alot

Comment: You're looking for Signalr.

Comment: Yeah I know about signalr but I dont know how you can use signalr to trigger from web api

Comment: Please do you know how or have sample code of how signalr can trigger a real time from a web api controller so that the mvc web chat view can see it